# GTM Enhanced Ecommerce - Checkout options only tracked for step 1

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce

I have a checkout form as follows: step 1 (Booking Details) and 2 (Customer Details) are part of a a SPA (Single Page Application), and step 3 (Payment Method Selection) is on a separate, dedicated page. For all steps I additionally want to track checkout options.

Before proceeding to step 3, the form input of step 1 and 2 are tracked to GA: this seems to work fine:

- The 'EE Checkout Option Tag' is fired twice (for step 1 and 2)
- The values of the dataLayer are correct
- The collect pixel is sent twice (200 OK), and contains the correct data (i.e. the checkout options I want to track)

However, when I look in Analytics, find my test order, and add 'Checkout Options' as a secondary dimension, I only see the checkout options for step 1.

[image]

[image]

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

### EEcommerce - Checkout

event **checkout** have to be called on every page of your checkout process with ceretain **step** parameter.

So you will have:

- checkout step 1 (Booking Details) -
- checkout step 2 (Customer Details) - in SPA this have to be called after step 1 (onscroll event, automatically or manually after opening tab with options selection)
- checkout step 3 (Payment Method Selection)

### EEcommerce - checkoutOption

event **checkoutOption** can be optionally called to **extend previous checkout** call with the **very same step** parameter.

- checkout_option step 1 (Booking Details) - send after users selection
- checkout_option step 2 (Customer Details) -  send after users or leaving the page to step 3
- checkout_option step 3 (Payment Method Selection) - send after users selection or when moving to purchase page

### Documentation

Documentation for GTM and EE ( https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#checkout ) is quite misleading, learn rather from https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#checkout-process

Comment: In my checkout flow, users can switch back and forth between step 1 and 2. As soon as they have placed their order (i.e. submit step 1 and 2), I track the Checkout Options for these steps (I wait with tracking because they can be edited still), before I redirect them to the next step: Payment Method Selection. Other than that, all tags are fired correctly, contain the right dataLayer value, and the collect pixels are OK, so I'm still not sure what I should do differently.